# Unexpected T_ELSE

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I've got a piece of code that I created and I've been 'requiring_once' in to my PHP code for quite a while now.  It works fine on my local PC, but when I upload it to my server it's coming up with the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/makequiz/public_html/nitpicker/func.php on line 47
```

Here's the function:

```
function howLongAgo($unix_time) {
// This function shows the unix time stamp 
// as number of seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years ago 


// Get the time difference between time specified and the current unix time 
$time_difference = time () - $unix_time;

$seconds_ago = $time_difference;
$minutes_ago = $time_difference / 60;
$hours_ago = $time_difference / 3600;
$days_ago = $time_difference / 86400;
$months_ago = $time_difference / 2629743;
$years_ago = $time_difference / 31556926;

if ($time_difference < 60) {
    // Seconds Ago 
    return round ( $time_difference ) . ' Seconds Ago';

} else if ( ($time_difference >= 60) && ($time_difference < 3600) ) {

    // Minutes Ago
    if (round ( $time_difference / 60 ) == 1) {
        return round ( $time_difference / 60 ) . " Minute Ago";
    } else {
        return round ( $time_difference / 60 ) . " Minutes Ago";
    }

} else if ($time_difference >= 3600 && $time_difference < 86400) {
    // Hours Ago 
    if (round ( $time_difference / 3600 ) == 1) {
        return round ( $time_difference / 3600 ) . " Hour Ago";
    } else {
        return round ( $time_difference / 3600 ) . " Hours Ago";
    }
} else if ($time_difference >= 86400 && $time_difference < 2629743) {
    // Days Ago 
    if (round ( $time_difference / 86400 ) == 1) {
        return round ( $time_difference / 86400 ) . " Day Ago";
    } else {
        return round ( $time_difference / 86400 ) . " Days Ago";
    }
} else if ($time_difference >= 2629743 && $time_difference < 31556926) {
    // Months Ago 
    if (round ( $time_difference / 2629743 ) == 1) {
        return round ( $time_difference / 2629743 ) . " Month Ago";
    } else {
        return round ( $time_difference / 2629743 ) . " Months Ago";
    }
} else if ($time_difference >= 31556926) {
    // Years Ago 
    if (round ( $time_difference / 31556926 ) == 1) {
        return round ( $time_difference / 31556926 ) . " Year Ago";
    } else {
        return round ( $time_difference / 31556926 ) . " Years Ago";
    }
}
}
```

This error is coming up, even though I haven't called the function at all in my code.

Can anyone see any errors in the code, cause I can't :(

Comment: Please point out line 47

Comment: The source you provided is correct. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: "even though I haven't called the function at all". That doesn't matter, parsing is parsing even though it's not called (which is not a good thing in the first place, why have it than?)

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically correct: http://codepad.org/YbYI0Rp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a lot simpler using a switch/case logic scheme. I have re-coded what you had up there using switch/case and this might be a good intro for you to learn switch/case. You had some extra ( ) in one of the if statements above. I hope this helps, friend:

```
<?
$unix_time = 6734;
echo howLongAgo($unix_time);

function howLongAgo($time_difference){

// Swtich logic based on the time difference passed to this function, sets the english string and what number the difference needs to be divided by
    switch($time_difference){
         case ($time_difference < 60):
              $string = " second";
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 60 && $time_difference < 3600):
              $string = " minute";
              $divider = 60;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 3600 && $time_difference < 86400):
              $string = " hour";
              $divider = 3600;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 86400 && $time_difference < 2629743):
              $string = " day";
              $divider = 86400;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 2629743 && $time_difference < 31556926):
              $string = " month";
              $divider = 2629743;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 31556926):
              $string = " year";
              $divider = 31556926;
              break;
    }

// If a divider value is set during the switch, use it to get the actual difference
if($divider){$diff = round($time_difference / $divider);}else{$diff = round($time_difference);}
// If the difference does not equal 1, pluralize the final result EG: hours, minutes, seconds
if($diff != 1){$pluralize="s";}
// Concatenate all variables together and return them
$final =  $diff . $string . $pluralize . " ago";
return $final;

}
?>
```

Comment: Also luke, here is the link to the switch function in the manual: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you very much for taking the time to alter the code for me, it is a lot tidier now, and the switch case is a lot more logical.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may come from the difference between elseif and else if (note the space).

From the PHP [website](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php):

> Note: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.

Comment: But he is using curly brackets everywhere, is he not?

Comment: From the docs: *Note that `elseif` and `else if` will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example.* ... so it should not make a difference here.

Comment: No, they are the same construct for the purposes of this example.  `} else if {}` is treated the exact same as `} else { if { } }`.  It's just convention...

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code at line 47 (I am going to bet you are missing a semi-color or bracket at line 46.

It does not matter if you are calling the function or not, as the php parser will analyze the entire file upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things..
did you change the file that it's included in when you loaded to your server?
try using include instead of require?