# Convert x hours x minutes ago back into unix timestamp

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I'm looking for a function to convert dates presented in "X Hours ago" and "X minutes ago" back into a timestamp in php, anyone have a soulution to this?

Comment: Why is this question tagged MySQL?

Comment: Because I want to insert it into MySQL after converting it, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant at all. You can print it and stick it on your head with superglue if you like, but it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) already does this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("8 hours ago");
```

See [relative time format specifications](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) for more info.

Comment: Thanks alot! I tought I allready tryed that, but something must have gone wrong. Worked just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I helped someone on stackoverflow to write a function that does the reverse of this, here is the code, i'm sure if you deconstruct and reverse it, you will have your answer:

```
<?
$unix_time = 6734;
echo howLongAgo($unix_time);

function howLongAgo($time_difference){

// Swtich logic based on the time difference passed to this function, sets the english string and what number the difference needs to be divided by
    switch($time_difference){
         case ($time_difference < 60):
              $string = " second";
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 60 && $time_difference < 3600):
              $string = " minute";
              $divider = 60;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 3600 && $time_difference < 86400):
              $string = " hour";
              $divider = 3600;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 86400 && $time_difference < 2629743):
              $string = " day";
              $divider = 86400;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 2629743 && $time_difference < 31556926):
              $string = " month";
              $divider = 2629743;
              break;
         case ($time_difference >= 31556926):
              $string = " year";
              $divider = 31556926;
              break;
    }

// If a divider value is set during the switch, use it to get the actual difference
if($divider){$diff = round($time_difference / $divider);}else{$diff = round($time_difference);}
// If the difference does not equal 1, pluralize the final result EG: hours, minutes, seconds
if($diff != 1){$pluralize="s";}
// Concatenate all variables together and return them
$final =  $diff . $string . $pluralize . " ago";
return $final;

}
?>
```

Comment: Kind of overkill. Also, this has a subtle bug in that it will not account for DST correctly (the intervals are hardcoded).

Comment: And doesn't answer the question. The two tasks are actually quite different.

Comment: that's merely a comment than an answer. Would have been enough to link it. Literally -1.

Comment: Sorry guys, just trying to help

Comment: Sounds like a huge amount of error-prone work for something you could handle with a single built-in function.

Comment: you should have seen the guys original function, it was if statements nested within if statements, all I did was take his logic and write the switch/case. What's the function that does this, I'll let him know there is a function built into PHP to convert time.

Comment: here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335940/unexpected-t-else/7337803

Answer (score 1):

```
$hourago= "-1 hour";
$minago = "-2 minute";

$timestamp = strtotime($hourago.' '.$minago);
echo $timestamp;
```

or

```
$hourago= "-1";
$minago = "-2";

$timestamp = strtotime($hourago.' hour '.$minago.' minute');
echo $timestamp;
```